# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Tags: android, dalvik

i guess there are a lot of reasons why Conversion to Dalvik format could fail with error 1, and there are alot of solutions offered in SO, but none of them worked for me... after wasting hours i finally  managed to solve it... i will post my own solution for this question for later reference and for the community. i hope this will be a time saver!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. go to Project tab
2. disable Build Automatically
3. remove bin library from your project
4. enable Build Automatically
5. try again!

Comment: Which would be kind of the same thing as cleaning all projects, which is the workaround I use.

Comment: @DigCamara cleanning out all project did not help me, as i said i went through all the suggestions i saw in related questions in SO none of them worked,only the one i wrote here...

Answer (score 0):

I am convinced that the anwser from Ofek works. Although let me clear it for you.

Usually dalvik problems happen when you have conflits with libraries in your project maybe because you added a library twice.

Maybe one in a lib folder and another from the Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries

Only one library should be used.

Comment: nope... tried playing with that for a while, wasnt my problem... it all began when i exported some of my project to a lib to be used by several other projects of mine. thats when i was introduced to alot of ADT bugs...

Comment: This problem happened to me when i have added KSoap2 library through the properties and then i added it to the lib folder. The solution i used was went to the java build path -> libraries and removed the library i had there. It only needed the one under lib folder

Comment: well im just happy that this very annoying bug is behind us now :)